# 8080/8085 Instruction Test Suite

Tags: assembly, 8080, 8085, testing

<sub>(This question was inspired by [Comprehensive test suites for MOS 6520 PIA / 6522 VIA / 6526 CIA](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/239/621))</sub>

Is there a comprehensive test suite for the Intel 808X series of processors?  Something that would test that the chip is operating properly, or an emulator has implemented all of the instructions properly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found three programs which together make up quite a comprehensive test suite.

- 8080/8085 CPU Diagnostic, version 1.0, by Microcosm Associates
- Diagnostics II, version 1.2, CPU test by Supersoft Associates
- 8080/8085 CPU Exerciser by Ian Bartholomew and Frank Cringles

The assembly of the Microcosm tests, and compiled `COM` programs of the other two tests suites can be found in [Alexander Demin's i8080-core repo](https://github.com/begoon/i8080-core), or on [my fork](https://github.com/JALsnipe/i8080-core) as a backup.  Unfortunately, it looks like the assembly is only available for Microcosm's test suite.